# Modify jquery to server-side for link true/false toggleClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

This code is in pseudo jquery, but how do I make it as jquery code?

I need this to toggle an icon on or off, depending on its selection from an admin page, then display this selection on other pages as a static badge status.

So these two snippets, can they be modified to include the toggle action from the second snippet into the first snippet?

I need it to work with C#, since the backend will be written in C#.

I am scouring the net to modify code like this, because I dont know jquery myself, I need to get help with it... :/

```js
//first snippet
$('a').click(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   var link = $(this).attr('href');
   $.ajax({
       method: post,
       url: '/link-tracking',
       data: {
          href: link   
     }
   });
}).done(function(url) { // pass the url back to the client after you incremented it
   window.location = url;
});

//second snippet
$('.verify').click(function() {
 var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
 $(this).toggleClass('verified');
$.post('/page.html', {
      'verified': $(this).hasClass('verified'),
      'id': id
    },
   function(data) {
      if (data.verified) {
       $(this).toggleClass('verified');    
   }
      //some sort of update function here
    });
});
```

Comment: _"can they be modified to include the toggle action from the second snippet into the first snippet?"_ Which portion of second snippet should be included at first snippet? Or should entire second snippet be included in first snippet?

Comment: @guest27134 Well, I dont know exactly how to implement them together. I would like the toggle action of the div to happen as shown in //second snippet so if there is a way to immerse the two somehow?

Comment: Using same `.verify` selector?

Comment: yes .verify if possible...

Comment: What should occur where references are to `$(this)` ?

Comment: (this) refers to the parent div, thus .verify is inside it, I guess...do you have a solution for me? Why isnt anyone else commenting either :(

Comment: _"(this) refers to the parent div, thus .verify is inside it,"_ Yes, though `this` would be the clicked `a` element within `$("a").on("click", function() {})` . If there are multiple `.verify` elements, which `.verify` should be selected to set `var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');` ? _"Why isnt anyone else commenting either"_ Not certain? Question is not entirely clear?

Comment: each one would have a unique id of course, I have to try to find out how to change the toggeClass to reflect this...So an admin person will turn on or off this toggle link, which will refer to verifying a users validity, then when a user sees their own profile, this toggle link selection on or off will be displayed on the user's page to signify that they are/are not verified, but the user themselves cannot toggle it, because the admin person has the permission only. does this make sense?

Comment: Not entirely clear what expected result is? Can you create ajsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314 http://codepen.io/krystyna93/pen/eZxWgW

Comment: This is how the toggle should preferably work. I dont know how I could mix the two, so when the link selection is changed, it will send this result to the db and then display the toggled result on other pages...The expected result is the change in the SVG icon color to orange (the default color is grey)

Comment: to also answer your last question ` 'id': id` that will select any id in the page with multiple toggle links

Comment: codepen does not return expected results? Do you want to change `html` at another open browser `tab` at click on `a` element?

Comment: @guest271314 I dont know what your meaning my 'expected result'??

Comment: @guest271314 The toggleClass changes the colour of the icon thats it. But I want to process this change somehow, so when someone clicks on it, it will get its value, and post this to a db to record the id of that click with verified, and then if the user clicks on it again, it will remove that id back to verify. It is seriously that hard to understand? Its like a 'favourite' button but Im not counting the clicks, I only want it to be either 0 or 1....

Comment: Which portion are you having issues with?

Comment: @guest271314 and when it is recorded in the db from the admin page, this will be displayed on user pages as the icon in grey or if its on as a orange icon.does that make sense?

Comment: can we chat, in the chat room , it might be easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111954/discussion-between-guest271314-and-krystyna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only single click handler appear necessary to meet requirement

```
$('.verify').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
  $(this).toggleClass('verified');
  $.post('/echo/json/', {json:JSON.stringify({
      'verified': $(this).hasClass('verified'),
      'id': id
      })
    },
    function(data) {
    console.log(data)
      if (data.verified) {
        // console.log(data)
      }
      //some sort of update function here
    });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/516rx7xa/1/